# Proof that any finite intersection of elements of a topology $\tau$ is again an element of $\tau$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am just starting my journey into point-set/general topology, I wanted to check my proof to see if I skipped any argumentation and if it makes sense. I thought it was a good idea to tackle the problem using induction:

> Let $(X, \tau)$ be any topological space. Prove that any finite number of intersections of elements of $\tau$,  is again an element of $\tau$.

Definition of a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$, we say $\tau$ is a topology if:

- $X, \emptyset  \in \tau$
- Any arbitrary union (finite or infinite) of elements in $\tau$ is again in $\tau$
- $A , B \in \tau $ then also $A \cap B \in \tau$

---

**My proof:**
We will first lay down a base case. This follows from the definition of a topological space. If $A_1,A_2 \in \tau$ then also $A_1 \cap A_2\in \tau$.

Suppose we now have $k$ arbitrary elements in $\tau$, label them by $A_1, A_2, A_2 \dots A_k \in \tau$ such that our induction hypothesis becomes:
$$ A:=\bigcap_{i=1}^k A_i \in \tau$$ 
Then observe if we take $k+1$ arbitrary elements from $\tau$, by associativity of set intersection, we first intersect $k$ elements and then the final $k+1 th$ element:
$$ \bigcap_{k=1}^{k+1} A_i =  \left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{k} A_i  \right)\cap A_{k+1}= A \cap A_{k+1} \in \tau$$
Now since $A\in \tau$ by our induction hypothesis and by definition $A_{k+1} \in \tau$. Then by definition of a topoloy this is again in $\tau$. By the principle of mathematical induction for any $n \in \mathbb N$ elements in $\tau$, the intersection of all these elements lies again in $\tau$

Is this a solid proof?

Comment: $\bigcup$ means union, not intersection.

Comment: I think you mean to say "the intersection of any finite number of ..." instead of "any finite number of intersections..."

Comment: Fixed * I used cap instead of cup - oops!

Comment: Yes, induction is a fine way to prove this.

Comment: Basically my proof boils down to using the fact that we can associate any finite number of intersections and then splitting off this term and realising it is in itself an element hence we reduce it so simple intersection of two elements. That, written down in neat mathematical language :) which is the tricky part.

Comment: Math101 aren't these two dual concepts though. When we count intersections we are also counting the amount of elements being intersected, which is just one greater than the amount of intersections. If we prove that we can intersect $n$ elements and the result is still in $\tau$. Would it not mean that I then take $n-1$ intersections, which can also be made arbitrarily large. Should I make this connection more clear?

Comment: What is your definition of a topological space? Isn't the fact that the intersection of finite number of elements of $\tau$ is again in $\tau$, a part of the definition?

Comment: This is left out in the definition and as an exercise one gets to prove that this follows from just defining it for two sets. This is that exercise. Basically now, yes, for any topology we know that finite intersections of its elements again lie in the topology. Now that I've done this exercise.

Comment: Your proof covers the case of intersecting $k$ sets when $k\geq2$. As one of the answers points out, you should also cover the case $k=1$, which is trivial (and provides an easier basis for the induction). Finally, you should also cover the case $k=0$. Fortunately, the intersection of no subsets of $X$ is $X$ itself, so this case is covered by the first clause in the definition of "topology".

Comment: @user170039. That $is$ the most common definition. The proposer is starting from a weaker form and proving it implies the common  form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the induction on $n$ is the usual way to go from closedness under a binary operation (associative usually) to closedness under the finitary version of that operation.

Don't call $\bigcap_{i=1}^k A_i$ by the name $X$, that's already taken for the whole space. Just $A$, e.g. is more logical.

Also, the base case is not needed, really, if you start at $k=1$. If $A_1 \in \tau$ then $\bigcap_{i=1}^1 A_i = A_1$ is in $\tau$ trivially. No topology axiom needed. Even the nullary intersection, usually taken to be $X$ by common convention, is in $\tau$, which at least does require an axiom.

The main reason ( I think) to formulate the topology axioms as involving just an intersection of two, instead of formulating them in terms of finite intersections right away, is (besides maybe a desire for minimality) the fact that the two-set-version might be slightly easier to check for a given collection of subsets that we want to prove to be a topology, easier notation etc.

Comment: indeed the books makes the reader check some basic examples using the simple definition, it' s a lot easier to check as you have fewer intersections to verify. I first had called the object $A$, but then realised it might be confusing, I picked the first letter I could think of, so X.... Although that had already been taken for the space.

Comment: For who is interested, this is the convention used in "topology without tears".